# Alter datatypes in the table -mysql

Tags: mysql

I need to alter the huge table around 200GB (INNODB). 
As i seen many blogs, there is suggestion for creating a new structure, copying the table content to new table and rename the tables.

As given below

```
CREATE TABLE WorkingTableNew LIKE WorkingTable;
ALTER TABLE WorkingTableNew MODIFY BigColumn VARCHAR(50);
INSERT INTO WorkingTableNew SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM WorkingTable;
ALTER TABLE WorkingTable RENAME WorkingTableOld;
ALTER TABLE WorkingTableNew RENAME WorkingTable;
DROP TABLE WorkingTableOld;
```

But if do above steps, How could we handle the newly inserted data into original table. Since many process updating and inserting the records into original table.

I have one master and 8 slaves

Comment: Trigger on WorkingTable that would catch all INSERT/UPDATE and store copy in third table (WorkingTableTemp). After you drop and rename WorkingTableNew with WorkingTable you could move data from WorkingTableTemp to WorkingTable

Comment: Can you lock the table for a while?

Comment: Trigger can not be used since inserting or updating the original records in bulk..

Comment: MySQL in the later versions like 5.6+ InnoDB supports online DDL which in most cases doesn't lock the table @juergend and topicstarter https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-create-index-overview.html.. p.s the online DDL supports gets better with newer MySQL versions make you have the correct documentation link for your MySQL version

Comment: "But if do above steps, How could we handle the newly inserted data into original table. Since many process updating and inserting the records into original table.

I have one master and 8 slaves Kindly suggest me on this." because you are running master and slave you might be able to contruct a inserterd/updated/deleted list from the binary log https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/binary-log.html

Comment: Also keep in mind `INSERT INTO WorkingTableNew SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM WorkingTable;` is a expensive command which can create a large temporary table (MyiSAM engine)  within the OS temp dir and consume alot off CPU, RAM end disk resources due to the copy.

Comment: @RaymondNijland thanks